# How do I represent a pair (two tuple) in Dafny?

Tags: dafny

How can I write a dafny `function` that takes in a sequence of ints and return a sequence of Pairs? e.g., input = [1,2], output = [Pair(1,1), Pair(1,2)]

I started with

```
function foo (l : seq<int>) : seq<Pair> 
{
  if |l| == 0 then [] 
  else new Pair() .... 
}
```

which doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `new` in a function, because functions are pure in Dafny they must not modify the heap. Either use [inductive datatypes](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leino/papers/krml243.html#sec-inductive-datatypes)

```
datatype Pair = Pair(fst:int, snd:int)

function foo (l : seq<int>) : seq<Pair> 
{
  if |l| <= 1 then [] 
  else [Pair(l[0],l[1])] + foo(l[2..]) 
}
```

Or use [tuples](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leino/papers/krml243.html#sec-tuple-types)

```
function foo (l : seq<int>) : seq<(int,int)> 
{
  if |l| <= 1 then [] 
  else [(l[0],l[1])] + foo(l[2..]) 
}
```